# Cross Validation with Autoencoders in R on MNIST dataset

Tags: r, cross-validation, autoencoders, keras

I was following this python guide and trying to emulate it in R: https://machinelearningmastery.com/evaluate-performance-deep-learning-models-keras/

there is this function called stratifiedKFold in Python which I found its equivalent to createFolds in R. I have two questions:

1. The documentation that the first input, the y, for createFolds is a vector of outcomes. Would that y be mnist\$test or mnist\$train\$y and mnist\$test\$y
2. when we call the fit function would the first two parameters be in terms of folds generated from CreateFolds or do I still use x_train and y_train

code below:

```
library(lattice)
library(ggplot2)
library(keras)
library(caret)

set.seed(1)

mnist <- dataset_mnist()
x_train <- mnist$train$x
y_train <- mnist$train$y
x_test <- mnist$test$x
y_test <- mnist$test$y

# reshape
dim(x_train) <- c(nrow(x_train), 784)
dim(x_test) <- c(nrow(x_test), 784)


# rescale
x_train <- x_train / 255
x_test <- x_test / 255

# one-hot encode to categories
y_train <- to_categorical(y_train, 10)
y_test <- to_categorical(y_test, 10)

# define 10-fold cross validation test harness
kfold <- createFolds(mnist$train, k = 10)

# running through each fold of the cross-validation
for (fold in kfold){
    model <- keras_model_sequential()
    model %>%
            layer_dense(units = 64, activation= "sigmoid", input_shape = c(784)) %>% # input
            layer_dropout(rate = 0.4) %>% # dropping points at random in between layers to avoid overfitting.
            layer_dense(units=128, activation = "sigmoid") %>% # hidden
            layer_dropout(rate = 0.3) %>% # dropping points at random in between layers to avoid overfitting.
            layer_dense(units = 10, activation = "sigmoid") # output

    # summary of the model.
    # summary(model)

    # compiling the model
    model %>% compile(
            loss = "mse",
            optimizer = optimizer_adam(),
            metrics = c("accuracy")
    )

    # fitting the model
    history <- model %>% fit(
            x_train, y_train,
            epochs = 5, batch_size = 64,
            validation_split = 0.2
    )

    # evaluating the performance of the model
    model %>% evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose = 0)
    # model %>% predict_classes(x_test)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a general machine learning problem, in order to avoid overfitting/underfitting, the network trains on training data, validates the training using a separate validation set and then evaluates the performance of the model on another separate test set.

However, by partitioning the available data into three sets, we drastically reduce the number of samples which can be used for learning the model, and the results can depend on a particular random choice for the pair of (train, validation) sets. A solution to this problem is a procedure called cross-validation (CV). A test set should still be held out for final evaluation, but the validation set is no longer needed when doing CV. In the basic approach, called k-fold CV, the training set is split into k smaller sets. A model is trained using k-1 of the folds as training data and the resulting model is validated on the remaining part of the data (i.e., it is used as a test set to compute a performance measure such as accuracy). The performance measure reported by k-fold cross-validation is then the average of the values computed in the loop. [(see here)](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html).

I have not had the chance to use `createFold` of R but I guess that it is a bit more different than `KerasClassifier` of Python. As far as I see, it creates index numbers and you should call those index numbers to divide your data set into k-folds.

```
install.packages('caret')
library(caret)
data(oil)
idx<- createFolds(oilType, 10)

sapply(idx, length)
#Fold01 Fold02 Fold03 Fold04 Fold05 Fold06 Fold07 Fold08 Fold09 Fold10 
#     8     10     10      9     10      9      9     12     10      9 

#Index numbers for the first fold
idx$Fold01
#[1]  7 14 34 40 50 57 71 76

#Extracting corresponding values
fattyAcids[idx$Fold01,]
#    Palmitic Stearic Oleic Linoleic Linolenic Eicosanoic Eicosenoic
#7       10.5     5.0  31.8     51.3       0.4        0.4        0.1
#14       9.7     5.6  35.2     47.8       0.5        0.4        0.2
#43       7.0     3.4  23.2     64.9       0.1        0.2        0.2
#49      11.5     5.1  27.8     54.5       0.2        0.4        0.1
#59      10.9     3.8  27.2     49.5       6.4        0.7        0.9
#80       4.8     1.8  62.6     20.0       9.5        0.1        1.4
#98      13.0     6.2  25.8     55.0       0.8        0.1        0.1
#103      6.1     4.1  25.1     63.5       0.5        0.1        0.1

#And so on... Create other folds.
```

Answering your questions, for  `createFolds` function, you need to call your training data set that you prepare beforehand. Then, you have to call k-1 of the folds (k=1,2,...,10 in the case of 10-fold CV) as training data (which are generated from CreateFolds), every time you run model.fit and validate on the remaining part of the data. Then, find the average of model metrics and evaluate your model by using your test data set.